# Can't use \circledast nor ^{º}

Tags: errors, warnings

sorry if this is a simple question, but I'm new to LaTeX and I'm willing to learn. I want to write this expression:

```
$r^{º}_{xy}[m]= \lbrace x \circledast \overline{y}^{-}  \rbrace$
```

but I get an error and a warning. The error states:

```
! Undefined control sequence. l.90 ...ón $r^{º}_{xy}[m]= \lbrace x \circledast
```

but if I remove the **\circledast** the error disappears. The warning has to do with the ^{º}, and it says:

```
LaTeX Warning: Command \textordmasculine invalid in math mode on input line 90.
```

Again, if I remove it from the expression then the warning disappears. By the way, I'm using the Palatino font, and I noticed that if I use the ordinary font I don't get these issues in the expression. But I like the Palatino font, so I would like to know how to deal with these problems.

Thanks in advanced

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! For `\circledast` you need `\usepackage{amssymb}`. I'm not sure why you would use `º` as an exponent. Shouldn't it be `r^{0}`, or maybe `r^{\circ}`?

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) please provide a full minimal example taht we can copy and try out.

Comment: @egreg Thank you very much. Using that package solved the \circledast issue. I was trying to use `º` as an exponent but it was completely wrong, what I really meant was `\circ`. It was for a circular correlation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\circledast` requires `\usepackage{amssymb}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
$r^{\circ}_{xy}[m]= \lbrace x \circledast \overline{y}^{-}  \rbrace$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you fix the answer with `\circ` instead of `º`?

Comment: @egreg of course.

Comment: @touhami: It's always a good idea to add some mortar to your answer in the form of descriptive references, not only code.

Comment: @Werner, thanks I'll try, my english is too bad

Comment: @touhami Don't worry about the language, somebody will be happy to help and fix the grammar.

Comment: @touhami how did you make that example picture of my code?

Comment: @JulianAilan Not me but Werner did.

Comment: Oh, right,  so @Werner how did you make that example picture?

Comment: @JulianAilan: Once the output was created and viewable, I followed these instructions: [How can I upload an image to be included in a question or answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2136/5764)